# R: comma was not fully recognized as separator when using read.table to load data

Tags: r

I have an issue that when loading a txt file to R by `read.table`, the separator comma was recognized in most lines. But it doesn't in some other lines that it was combined with its former and later characters into a new one.

This is how I load data:

```
all_fund <- read.table("data.txt", sep=",", fill=T ,encoding="UTF8",
                        colClasses = c("character", "character", "character"))
```

Here is part of the result you can see that, in row 11, the column `V3` is blank and its data **000835** was combined with comma into column `V2`. (sorry if those Chinese characters don't display correctly at your PC)

```
> all_fund
                            V1                              V2     V3
1   <U+FEFF>序号,基金简称,基金代码                                       
2                                1        方正富邦保险主题指数分级 167301
3                                2           易方达沪深300非银ET 000950
4                                3        国泰国证食品饮料行业指数 160222
5                                4        广发中证全指建筑材料指数 004856
6                                5        广发中证全指建筑材料指数 004857
7                                6            国泰国证航天军工指数 501019
8                                7           汇添富中证主要消费ETF 000248
9                                8               易方达上证50指数C 004746
10                               9               易方达上证50指数A 110003
11                              10    华润元大富时中国A50指,000835       
12                              11               天弘中证证券保险A 001552
```

I paste part of the text file data here in case you need it.

```
序号,基金简称,基金代码
1,方正富邦保险主题指数分级,167301
2,易方达沪深300非银ET,000950
3,国泰国证食品饮料行业指数,160222
4,广发中证全指建筑材料指数,004856
5,广发中证全指建筑材料指数,004857
6,国泰国证航天军工指数,501019
7,汇添富中证主要消费ETF,000248
8,易方达上证50指数C,004746
9,易方达上证50指数A,110003
10,华润元大富时中国A50指,000835
11,天弘中证证券保险A,001552
```

Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: I wondered it at well but actually all comma are English comma. So you didn't see this error?